# Is there a way to code instructions to a user that include information their input?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm new to Javascript and writing some code in which I prompt a user for the maximum number that they want in guessing a game between 1 and their maximum number.

After receiving their input, I need to create a message that changes instructions of the game, based on the maximum number they gave.

```js
function do_max(prompt) {
  let valid_input = false;
  let max_num, input;

  let message = document.getElementById("max-message");

  while (!valid_input) {
    input = window.prompt(prompt);

    max_num = Number(input);

    if (max_num != NaN && max_num > 0) {
      valid_input = true;
      val = Math.round();
      message.innerHTML = "Choose a number between 1 and (" + Number + ").";
    }
  }
}
do_max("Enter a number")
```

```html
<p id="max-message"></p>
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm stuck on that message. Any help?

Comment: Did you mean to use `max_num` instead of `Number` in the message?

Comment: `Math.round()` is also not going to do anything, except for maybe error out.

Comment: I tried using both, but both times, the code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

On `val = Math.round()`, there is no property for now. You need to put `max_num` as input param on `Math.round` function and put `val` inside `innerHTML` as follows.

```js
function do_max(prompt) {
    let valid_input = false;
    let max_num, input;
    
    let message = document.getElementById("max-message");

    while(!valid_input) {
        input = window.prompt(prompt);

        max_num = Number(input);

        if(max_num != NaN && max_num > 0) {
            valid_input = true;
            const val = Math.round(max_num);
            message.innerHTML = "Choose a number between 1 and ("+ val +").";
        }
    }
}

do_max("Max Number");
```

```html
<p id="max-message"></p>
```

Comment: Should also be `const val = ...` or `let val = ...`